# Run a Macro after changing a value on a data validation dropbox

Tags: excel, vba

A good person helped me creating the following code and it works fine  when you manually enter a value on any cell under column B but when I try to use the same code  when the value is select from data validation drop box is not working , do I need to change something ?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("B")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim rng As Range
        For Each rng In Intersect(Target, Columns("B"))
            If rng.Row > 2 Then ' your sample code seemed to suggest that this should start on row 3 and higher
                Call Settime(rng.Row)
            End If
        Next rng
    End If
Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Sub Settime(rw as long)
    If range("B" & rw) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Ingrese El account Number" 
    Else
        Range("J" & rw & ":K" & rw) = Range("J" & rw & ":K" & rw).value
    End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: The event triggers for me when selecting a value from a validation list in column B. Is the box which sets the value located in a userform, or something like that, or is there some other code somewhere in your project which could have disabled events?

Comment: The above code works only if you enter manually the values on column B but if you create a data validation list on column B and then you select a random value  the macro does not work anymore

Comment: As I stated it does trigger for me, when selecting a value from a validation list, so it seems there is something which is not apparent from the code above which causes the macro to fail.

Comment: Im trying to use the same code for a different column but Im getting Ambiguous name detected Worrksheet_ Change how can I fix it ?

Comment: The code works for me too, using data validation dropdown in column B. To fix the latter error, you cannot have more than one `Worrksheet_ Change` event for one worksheet. Add the new test column (X in my case) to the condition `If Not Intersect(Target, Range(Columns("B"), Columns("X"))) Is Nothing Then`

Comment: The problem is that if a user enter a value on any cell under column X it needs to call a different macro not the same :S